# Is there any way to delete or alter file history changes in a Team Foundation Studio repository?

Tags: tfs

A team member's username/password was inadvertently checked in to a file in source control. While the person will likely have to change their username and password anyway, is there any way to delete this history of the file from TFS?

Ideally, we could just blank out the password within the history. I found where the data is stored in SQL, but the data is hashed, so I can't just edit it directly (I don't think).

Thank you.

Comment: If anyone is curious, I was able to update the record of the changeset from the SQL table. TFS now just hops over this record and it works perfectly. The change is still in there somewhere, but I am happy with the fact that it is hashed. I can't recommend this as a solution though. You need to very careful in editing tables from someone else's programs!

Answer (score 17):

Generally speaking, history is mostly immutable, however you can destroy items that were errantly checked in using the `tf destroy` command.  For example:

```
tf destroy $/Project/Folder/file.txt
```

will permanently delete all references to that file in history.

(To clarify what I mean by "mostly immutable": aside from being able to destroy historic items, you cannot modify version control history, that is the changes that comprise a changeset.  However, some version control *metadata* can be changed, including changeset comments, work item associations, and check-in notes.)

Comment: This is good and helpful information, so +1. However, I don't want to lose all the other history on the file so it's not a good solution for me.

Comment: @Edward Is it possible to destroy a tfs folder?
my tfs made a huge mess with a project. Now i have to delete an rebuild the whole project. But when i do so, the history on the folder stills available (because it has the same name) and the problem is still there.

Comment: @daniel Yes, you can destroy a folder or a file.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thanks. Worked great

Comment: This is unfortunate in coordination with the way it handles rollbacks. If you roll back a file, from that point forward, if you annotate the file, all of the rolled back lines become "your" change. In a file where someone made drastic changes, the entire file can appear as changed by you as of the rollback changeset.